# PHP - Combine multiple API endpoints in array

Tags: php, arrays, api

I am trying to create a small function to load data from different API endpoints into one array to work with / load data from. Right now my code is looking as follow;

```
$url1 = 'https://gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/gameinfo/guilds/uhmotNBAQ6-0vi9PFysRBg/members';
$url2 = 'https://gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/gameinfo/guilds/DWkD4B0uSsGQoryrz8Nuwg/members';
$url3 = 'https://gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/gameinfo/guilds/wSbCgimqTPy470n-wDQXPQ/members';
$url4 = 'https://gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/gameinfo/guilds/nmc0HQW-TZirTlnGzwbF-w/members';
$url5 = 'https://gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/gameinfo/guilds/WpV4yaVxSLW8QXH2Be40cA/members'; 

$api_endpoint1 = json_decode(file_get_contents($url1), true); 
$api_endpoint2 = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2), true); 
$api_endpoint3 = json_decode(file_get_contents($url3), true); 
$api_endpoint4 = json_decode(file_get_contents($url4), true); 
$api_endpoint5 = json_decode(file_get_contents($url5), true);

$merged_data = array();

foreach ($api_endpoint1 as $data) {
    foreach ($api_endpoint2 as $data2) {
        $merged_data[] = array_merge($data, $data2[$data['Name']]);
    }
}

var_dump($merged_data);
```

It doesn't work as I tried so many things the past two days, I came to search for help.

Comment: You're not actually using an array. Consider `$url[1] = ...` and so on, or even a for loop since the only thing that changes is at the end. Having said that, what isn't working? Right now, it appears you're just doing some sort of array_merge, not actually calling the API itself. Also remember that APIs sometimes have rate limits and may not want you hitting their server that fast.

Comment: @barrycarter I am lost in how I can actually merge the API data into one "array" it has multiple guild members endpoints and I want to put them eventually into a dropdown to choose from.

Comment: Just to doublecheck, you understand the difference between `$url1` and `$url[1]`, yes?

Comment: @barrycarter I do, $url1 is just the variable holding data and $url[1] is taking the second object from an array since an array starts at 0.

Comment: True. I'm suggesting you use an array where your $url1 becomes $url[0], $url2 becomes $url[1] and so on.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks. I will update my post once I have done that and still having issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246510/discussion-between-barrycarter-and-caleb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to @barrycarter for his help in pushing me into the right direction.

The actual code needed to be like this:

```
$url1 = 'gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/…';
$url2 = 'gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/…';
$url3 = 'gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/…';
$url4 = 'gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/…';
$url5 = 'gameinfo.albiononline.com/api/…';

$merged_urls = [$url1, $url2, $url3, $url4, $url5];

$api_endpoint = [];

foreach ($merged_urls as $urls) {
$api_endpoint[] = file_get_contents($urls);
}

// Gives all DATA from all Guilds members
// var_dump($api_endpoint);

$merged_arrays = array_merge(json_decode($api_endpoint[0], true), json_decode($api_endpoint[1], true), json_decode($api_endpoint[2], true), json_decode($api_endpoint[3], true), json_decode($api_endpoint[4], true));


foreach ($merged_arrays as $query) {
echo $query['Name'];
echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: The beauty of the loop is wasted if you are going to manually type: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.  You shouldn't be declaring single string variables like `$url1` in the first place.

Comment: I don't see why you actually need to merge anything.  https://3v4l.org/ZJikL  If you need help accessing names within the generated array, we can help with that.

Comment: @barrycarter has show me how to beautify this and make things a lot easier to read and use. Thankyou for your comments. Really appreciate it!

Comment: I feel like you don't understand my feedback.  I'll give you some time to compare my demo with your posted snippet.

Comment: @mickmackusa https://github.com/Ralumbi/fed-albion-tools/blob/main/Public/Templates/Default/contact.php this is what I got helped with. The solution I posted was more as of how I solved it myself with some pushes in the back. I really appreciate your help as well, all of you here are making me a better php programmer.